# Attach to specific tmux session using Iterm2

Tags: tmux, iterm2

I know that I can connect iterm2 to a tmux session using tmux -CC attach. However, I don't know how to attach Iterm2 to a specific tmux session if I have more than 1 running at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tmux -CC attach -t SESSION_NAME` to attach to a specific session.

If you run this from iTerm, it starts a new iTerm window with all the panes you had in that session loaded as iTerm native panes.

Eg. If `tmux ls` shows sessions 0, 1, 2, `tmux -CC attach -t 1` will attach to session 1.

Eg. If `tmux ls` shows sessions projectA and projectB, `tmux -CC attach -t projectA` will attach to the session named projectA.